# How to generate totals of fields from related model records

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to work out how to generate totals of fields from related model records.

Example: I have 2 Google Drive Table models (Projects & Stages) with a relation where 1 Project can have many Stages. The Stages model has a number of fields, one of which is Budget.

I'm trying work out how to display a Total Project Budget, which is the sum of the Budget fields of the Stages related to each Project.

I'm really stuck on getting this to work and wondering if I need to create a client script, server script, or calculated model, or if there's an easy way to do this directly within a binding.

Here is a link to a bunch of screen-grabs of what I'm trying to build, the UI and setup in App Maker:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wt00virvn88puyi/AACy7-fPLYFF1H9uFkvEuvgTa?dl=0

Comment: Can you please share more details about your UI (is it a table with page of N projects or is it a project details view or you are working on some reprort view where you need to aggregate data about all your projects, etc...)?

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I've updated the original post with more details and [screengrabs](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wt00virvn88puyi/AACy7-fPLYFF1H9uFkvEuvgTa?dl=0). I also corrected my use of 'datasource' to 'models'. Any help/pointers you can offer much appreciated.

Comment: I do need to aggregate data about all projects, calculated from the details of stages within each project. The actual app will have many more types or aggregated report views and projects and stages will eventually have a lot more information than is in the screengrabs above - I'm just doing one step at a time whilst I learn my way around AppMaker. If I can get this to work, it will become a core part of my business workflow for my teams to use.

Comment: At least for the project list page I would recommed to go with Calculated Datasource. You can find some good samples in templates(https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/), particularly in Project Tracker(https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/).

Answer (score 0):

[Datasource](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#DataSource) has client event onLoad, so you can calculate value in this event, find widget, which shows total, and set text of this widget.

Comment: Thanks Andrey! It took a while to figure out what you meant through the reference manual, but you pointed me in the right direction to work it out!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by creating the following client script, after studying Andrey's suggestion & link (thanks!). I call the script whenever the totals need recalculating (i.e. onValueChange of existing Stages, and onAttach/Detach for new or deleted Stages. Works nicely.

```
function updateProjectTotals() {
    var currentProject = app.datasources.Projects.item;
    var totals = {ProjectName:currentProject.ProjectName, Stages:0, Progress:0, Budget:0};
    var stages = currentProject.Stages;
    stages.forEach(function(item){
        totals.Progress += item.StageProgress;
        totals.Budget += item.StageBudget;  
    });
    totals.Stages = stages.length;
    totals.Progress = (totals.Progress/totals.Stages);
    var record = app.datasources.Projects.item;
    record.ProjectProgress = totals.Progress;
    record.ProjectBudget = totals.Budget;
}
```

Comment: It will work while you can fit all your stages on a page(or load them in one request to client)... If you definetely know, that you allways will be able to load all your stages on client then maybe it is okish solution. The only impovement I would recommend is converting your model properties to page custom properties (it looks like you introduced ProjectProgress and ProjectBudget model fields exclusively for UI bindings).